# Best statistical approach for determining a significant cutoff value?

Tags: regression, t-test, group-differences

Assume a study comparing fingernail length to incidence of fungal infection. Ultimately, the goal is to determine a maximum length to propose for use by animal care takers.

One proposed approach: 1st perform a regression (# of individuals with fungus ~ nail length) to determine if there is a linear trend. If the trend is not strictly linear, it was proposed we use graphical exploratory analyses to visualize any clear transitions in the trend (from low to high incidence). Using this "cut-off" value, we would bin the data into 2 groups and then use a t-test to statistically analyze whether the two groups (say those with > 2 cm nails vs those with <2 cm nails) have significant differences in fungal infection.

Is this sensible, or is there a more elegant or more appropriate approach?

Comment: This sounds more like a logistic regression  or classification problem; do you have incidence data only, eg you only have data on infected nails, but not uninfected?  The ideal model would be infectedYesNo ~ length

Comment: @NBrouwer the data is planned to only consist of infected nails (and therefore will not include data for individuals without infected nails). This is a limitation of the data source.

Comment: @theforestecologist that sounds like a major problem, like it's not possible to answer your research question with this data.

Comment: @John Madden could you elaborate a bit more about why (and possibly suggest alternatives)

Comment: Let $X$ be fingernail length and $Y$ be infection status. You have collected data from the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=$infected. You are interested in the converse, the probability of $Y$=infection given $X$. It is not possible to go from one to the other without additional information. In order to be at all certain about what's going on, you would need fingernail measurements from similarly situated but uninfected animals. In a pinch, we could also make due with assumptions about the general distribution of fingernail lengths in the population.

Comment: @JohnMadden You may want to consider adding this as an answer

Comment: @JohnMadden could we not make claims about the conditional distribution? (i.e., among infected individuals, we hypothesize that there will be greater number of infections with longer nail length).

Comment: @JohnMadden is the above ok? OR is that also an issue? OR is the issue trying to apply the cutoff?

Comment: You could totally do that, if it would be useful for you to know, e.g. that 90% of infected toenails are at least 2 cm long, without being able to say whether or not 90% of uninfected toenails are also that length. It's just not clear to me how this would lead to a practical recommendation, since we can't say anything about when a length becomes more characteristic of an uninfected fingernail than an infected one.

Comment: @theforestecologist Regarding your point about the conditional distribution, you can only make statements about probability of length conditional on disease status, but it sounds like you want probability of disease status  conditional on nail length.  That's different

Answer (score 5):

A dataset which is comprised solely of infected individuals  will not answer your question.

In short, you can not determine correlation without variation, and since your disease status does not vary (between disease positive and disease negative) you can not effectively correlate nail length and disease.

Here is a simple illustration.  Suppose that there is no relationship with nail length and disease (which is maybe false, but this is for demonstration purposes).  However, there are naturally more animals with longer nails in your sample.  Your proposed approach of a regression on count of infected individuals would show a positive correlation even though one does not exist.

I've gone ahead and created a sample dataset in R to verify this to you

```r
library(tidyverse)
# Same regardless of nail lenth,
baseline_risk <- 0.2
nail_lengths <- 1:6
nail_length_prob <- 1:6/ sum(1:6)

sample_size <- 1000

tibble(
  nail_length = sample(nail_lengths, replace=T, prob = nail_length_prob, size=sample_size),
  infected = rbinom(sample_size, 1, baseline_risk)
) %>% 
  # select only disease positive individuals
  filter(infected==1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(nail_length, infected)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

The plot appears to show a correlation between nail length and number of diseased animals, but we *know for certain none exists because we simulated these data*.  You're just seeing that there are more animals with longer nails, and naturally there will be more diseased animals with longer nails because there is a larger base of individuals to infect.

You need disease negative individuals as well so you can estimate the probability of infection given the nail length.  Trying to determine a cut off based only on counts of diseased individuals could be possible, but faces serious limitations.

Comment: nice answer btw the political scientists call this situation "selecting on the dependent variable" which is a decent search term.